# custom-set-faces not working for client

Tags: init-file, faces, emacsclient, server, customize-face

I have a custom `(custom-set-faces ...)` section in my `~/.emacs` file. When I run emacs this section seems to get completely ignored since the custom colours don't get set. But if I go to `~/.emacs`, highlight the section and run it with `M-x eval-region` then the colours load correctly. Why is `custom-set-faces` getting silently ignored?

Comment: Do you run Emacs using the daemon and `emacsclient` ?

Comment: If you are using *daemon-client*, then `custom-set-faces` sets the face of frame `F1`, which is actually invisible. I encountered this issue yesterday...

Comment: Please show your `custom-set-faces` code, at least the relevant part.

Comment: @TristanRiehs  @shynur Indeed, I connect to Emacs by daemonizing it and then using `emacsclient`.

Comment: Then does this answer your question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72730/40641 ?

Comment: I don't know ELisp well enough to adapt that code to settings I have in `custom-set-faces`. I tried calling `custom-set-faces` by putting it inside the hook like this: `(defun efs/set-font-faces () (custom-set-faces ...))`, but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```lisp
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
          (lambda ()
            (custom-set-faces
             "Put your original “(custom-set-faces ...)” here!")))
```

to your configuration.

---

I guess the problem you encountered has to do with the order of actions at Emacs startup:

> When Emacs is started up, it performs the following operations (see `normal-top-level` in `startup.el`):

> 10. If appropriate, it creates a graphical frame.
>     As part of creating the graphical frame, it initializes the window system specified by `initial-frame-alist` and `default-frame-alist` for the graphical frame, by calling the `window-system-initialization` function for that window system.
>     **This is *not done in* batch (noninteractive) or *daemon mode*.**
> 11. It initializes the initial frame’s faces, and sets up the menu bar and tool bar if needed.
>     If graphical frames are supported, it sets up the tool bar even if the current frame is not a graphical one, since a graphical frame may be created later on.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work both in daemon mode and in normal mode? While I run Emacs by daemonizing it, I also have it as my default git commit message editor. With your proposed solution all seems to work fine in daemon mode, but when editing git messages in standalone mode fonts are not customized properly.

Comment: @JanStolarek  I was able to get the behavior you desire by adding this line after the `(add-hook...)` code: `(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook \n
            face-customizer)`  where the `\n` is a new line.

Comment: @mikemtnbikes: You can omit that `newline`.

Comment: @shynur Thanks for note, I figured it was unnecessary, but wasn't sure.